# Gnuplot tikz terminal, how to add commands to the picture?

Tags: plot, latex, gnuplot, tikz

I have some gnuplot code that makes a graph using the tikz terminal. However, I want to add to the generated `.tex` file some tikz code.

As a MWE, consider the following gnuplot code:

```
set term tikz standalone
set output "out.tex"
plot sin(x)
```

Let's say I want to draw a circle on the plot generated, which I can do using `\draw (2,2) circle [radius = 2cm]`. Adding this line to the `.tex` file generated yields the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{\gpbboxborder}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot]


%!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
%!! ADDED BY HAND
\draw (2,2) circle [radius = 2cm];
%!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


%% generated with GNUPLOT 5.0p3 (Lua 5.1; terminal rev. 99, script rev. 100)
...
```

Is there any way to tell gnuplot that I want some tikz code on the picture, so it outputs a `.tex` file similar to the one I made? Reading the docs I've found that with this terminal you can set a preamble but you can't include tikz code there.
Another option I was considering was using `set print output_file` and then `print` the code I want, however, either that code gets printed first in the file and gnuplot overwrites it or printing it after gnuplot has printed the output overwrites it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this comes close:

```
set label 1 "\\tikz{\\draw [green] (2,2) circle [radius = 2cm];}" at screen 0.0, screen 0.0

set label 2 "by gnuplot" textcolor rgb "#00FF00" at 0, -0.6
set label 3 "manual" textcolor rgb "#0000FF" at 0, -0.5

set term tikz standalone
set output "out.tex"
plot sin(x)
```

There is a small offset compared to the circle generated by your handmade draw command, but it might be close enough.

Please note that this approach does not directly place a `draw` command in the generated tex file, it puts the `draw` command into a `node`. I think this causes the offset. Gnuplot generates this:

```
\node[gp node left] at (0.000,0.000) {\tikz{\draw [green] (2,2) circle [radius = 2cm];}};
```

[image]

Don't forget to escape the backslashes. The option `screen` after `set label at` tells gnuplot to place the label relative to the screen coordinate system, have a look at `help coordinates` from gnuplot commandline.

Comment: If you try to draw the circle in another place, like ´(5,5)´, the circle will be drawn where it is in your graph. I've tried drawing something else and it is always drawn in the bottom left corner. I've also tried with including a ´tikzpicture´ environment and a matrix node as it was suggested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/in-tikz-is-it-possible-to-nest-nodes but nothing has worked. Since everything is being put into a node, it may be worth making a script instead to add that code into the .tex file.

Comment: Ah, you are right. It seems to ignore the (2,2) or (5,5) completely. Or the (2,2) is relative to the node, and the content of the node is trimmed. But what about moving the label to the correct position, like `set label 1 "\\tikz{\\draw [green] (0,0) circle [radius = 2cm];}" at -5, -0.2`? The `at -5, -0.2` is the lower left corner of the node. I know, finding the correct coordinates might be difficult. Maybe an external script (that could be called with `system`) is a cleaner solution.